# Each thread accessing and modifying one element from a 2D array

Tags: java, multithreading, multidimensional-array

I'm wanting to have it so each time a new thread passes through the `run()` method, they access a different element of the 2D array.

For example, the first thread would access and modify `2DArray[0][0]`:

```java
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        // Thread accesses 2DArray[0][0]
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

The second thread then takes over and accesses/modifies the second index `2DArray[0][1]` and so on:

```java
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        // Thread accesses 2DArray[0][1]
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

If I had a matrix of 10x10, I'd want to create 10 threads, each working on 1 element from the 2D array all at the same time

I just can't seem to wrap my head around the logic, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, java doesn't have 2d arrays, you only cant create an array of arrays. So it's 2DArray[0][1], not 2DArray[0,1]. Because of that you shouldn't handle elements of secondary arrays in different threads. One thread should work with 2DArray[0] and the other one with 2DArray[1]

Second, since you want the second thread to take over only after the first one has finished processing previous element, you get no benefit from multithreading, so why would you want to do that. You could write that same code in a single thread.

Third, you want to change values for first row only? That looks weird.

If you still have you reasons to do that, then you should create a lock, which a currently working thread would acquire and a variable to hold current element index.

While active thread works, others wait to acquire the lock. And do that until current element index reaches length of array.

**UPDATE**

Here is a solution randomizing all rows in parallel. Please, pay attention, that thread pool consists of 4 threads only. You can change it to any value, java will do balancing for you.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class RandomizeFunc implements Callable<Void> {
    private final int[] row;

    public RandomizeFunc(int[] row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        ThreadLocalRandom localRandom = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            int randomValue = localRandom.nextInt();
            row[i] = randomValue;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class RandomizeArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int[][] array = new int[10][];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            array[i] = new int[10];
        }

        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        List<Callable<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<>(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tasks.add(new RandomizeFunc(array[i]));
        }
        threadPool.invokeAll(tasks);
        boolean workFinishedInTime = threadPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (!workFinishedInTime) {
            threadPool.shutdownNow();
        }
        for (int[] row : array) {
            for (int col : row) {
                System.out.print(col + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Or there's a solution using naked Threads . Not recommended, but might help understand what is going on.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

class RandomizingThread extends Thread {
    private final int[] row;

    public RandomizingThread(int[] row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ThreadLocalRandom localRandom = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            int randomValue = localRandom.nextInt();
            row[i] = randomValue;
        }
    }
}

public class RandomizeArrayWithNakedThreads {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int[][] array = new int[10][];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            array[i] = new int[10];
        }

        List<Thread> threadPool = new ArrayList<>(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            RandomizingThread worker = new RandomizingThread(array[i]);
            worker.start();
            threadPool.add(worker);
        }
        for (Thread worker : threadPool) {
            worker.join();
        }
        for (int[] row : array) {
            for (int col : row) {
                System.out.print(col + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Third, you want to change values for first row only? That looks weird." -
The code was just an example, after completing the first row, I'd want the threads to then start on the first index of the second row and so on.

Is there a way to have 10 threads access 10 elements from the matrix all at the same time?

Comment: Yes there is, but it's the best way to make your code run as slow as possible. If you modify elements if the same array in different threads it's going to be several times slower, than just doing it in a single thread. If you want speed, you should have a thread for each row, not for each column

Comment: Could you provide a simple code example on how to get a thread to modify each element in one row?

Comment: Sure, just wait a little bit please. I'll update my answer

Comment: Added demo solution to my answer